# JQuery проверка открыта ли кнопка

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

помогите пожалуйста всю голову сломал.
У меня есть следующая конструкция: кнопка при нажатии на которую вылезает ниже div, и таких кнопок 5. Когда нажимаешь на кнопку - все кнопки включая её расширяются, а когда кнопка закрыта, то все кнопки принимают предыдущие параметры.
Так вот, проблема в следующем: Мне нужно чтобы если все кнопки закрыты, то все кнопки получают предыдущие характеристики, а сейчас это работает так, что если любая кнопка закрывается, то все кнопки принимают пред.характеристики. Если открыть две кнопки и закрыть одну из них, получается что все кнопки принимают прежние характеристики кроме одной. А мне нужно чтобы они принимали прежние характеристики только в случае, если все кнопки закрыты. Это ломает вёрстку.
Я пытался сделать проверку с булевой переменной, но не вышло. Потом создал функцию с параметром типа int. При нажатии на кнопку в эту кнопку передавалась единица, как сигнал, что кнопка открыта. Но тут проблема в том, что я не могу отличать открыта она или нет, потому что сигнал в ф-ию передаётся посредством метода $("button").click(function() {isopen(1);}) То-есть при каждом нажатии.

Пожалуйста помогите мне с решением моей проблемы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
  $("#btn1faq").click(function() {
    isopen = true;
        ++count;
      
        $("#hiddencase1").show();
    $(".afterjsdiv1").css("position", "relative");
    $(".afterjsdiv1").css("left", "-4.9em");
    $(".daunstr").css("left", "45em");

    $("div.afterjsdiv1 > .hrdivdownS").css("width", "44em");

    $("#dstr1").hide();

        $(".upstr").css("left", "45em");
    $(".upstr").css("top", "3em");
    $(".upstr").show();

    
        if(count==2) {
    isopen = false;
    count=0;
    $("#hiddencase1").hide();
    $(".afterjsdiv1").css("position", "relative");
    $(".afterjsdiv1").css("left", "0em");
    $(".daunstr").css("left", "40em");
    $("div.afterjsdiv1 > .hrdivdownS").css("width", "40em");
    $(".upstr").hide();
    $(".daunstr").show();
    
        }
  });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте класс для кнопки, который будет опознавательным знаком. И почему бы вообще стили не вынести в css?

Comment: Хоть кто-то понял что автор хочет?

Comment: @ПростаMiha Если честно дальше заголовка и картинок ничего не смотрел :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хз что я тут написал, но надеюсь хоть на 1 процент попал в задачю

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block-title');
const main = document.querySelector('.main');

for (elem of blocks) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', openSubMenu);
}

function openSubMenu() {
  this.parentElement.classList.toggle('active');
  
  let activeElem = document.querySelector('.block.active');
  if (activeElem != null) {
    main.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    main.classList.remove('active');
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  position: relative;
  transition: .25s;
}

.main.active .block-title{
  margin: 0 48px;
}

.block-title {
  z-index: 12;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6));
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block-arrows {
  display: flex;
}

.block-arrows > img {
  margin: 0 12px;
}

.block-arrows > img:last-child {
  opacity: 0;
}

.block.active .block-arrows > img:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
}

.block-submenu {
  transition: .5s;
  max-height: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -9;
}

.block.active .block-title {
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 8px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, .6));
}

.block.active .block-submenu {
  transition: .5s;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block-title">
      <h1>Lorem</h1>
      <div class="block-arrows">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/24/undefined/external-arrow-arrows-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons-13.png" />
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/24/undefined/external-arrow-arrows-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons-9.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-submenu">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="block-title">
      <h1>Lorem</h1>
      <div class="block-arrows">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/24/undefined/external-arrow-arrows-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons-13.png" />
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/24/undefined/external-arrow-arrows-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons-9.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-submenu">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="block-title">
      <h1>Lorem</h1>
      <div class="block-arrows">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/24/undefined/external-arrow-arrows-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons-13.png" />
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/24/undefined/external-arrow-arrows-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons-9.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-submenu">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="block-title">
      <h1>Lorem</h1>
      <div class="block-arrows">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/24/undefined/external-arrow-arrows-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons-13.png" />
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/24/undefined/external-arrow-arrows-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons-9.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-submenu">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="block-title">
      <h1>Lorem</h1>
      <div class="block-arrows">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/24/undefined/external-arrow-arrows-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons-13.png" />
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/24/undefined/external-arrow-arrows-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons-9.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-submenu">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Изумительно, вы попали в точку. Так и знал что код как чайник написал